# A word that describes a core feature involved?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

I have made an application which is mostly programmed in PHP, but have also used some other languages. Now I want to describe that I have made a program that is "corely" programmed in PHP, but still remember that my application have mostly made on PHP.

*Corely* is not in dictionary. What should be a word for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use **predominantly**, **primarily** or **principally** to say either the largest or most important portion is written in PHP, while quantity alone can be stressed with words like **chiefly**, **mainly**, **mostly**, or **largely**.

If you want to say the main or most important part of the code is in PHP and peripheral functionality in other languages, you could reword along the lines of

> The core of the code is written in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

[*Crux*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crux) might be useful to you:

> The basic, central, or essential point or feature.

Answer (score -3):

Strictly from an experienced programmer's advice, I'll suggest that you go with something like :

> My program **majorly** uses PHP

You should also describe further, for eg: My program is majorly based on PHP and it makes use of HTML for front-end.

Comment: -1: *Majorly* is barely a "word" at all - it certainly shouldn't be advanced to a non-native speaker as a credible alternative to any of the suggestions put forward by @choster